# Spring @Controller which calls an @Async method then calls get() on the returned Future....code smell?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I'm looking at a spring @Controller method that calls an @Async method, does some "other stuff", then calls `.get()` on the `Future` returned by the async method call.

I can see how this may improve the response time of the controller as both the async method and "other stuff" involves calling web services and sure, why not execute multiple ws calls in parallel. But to do this inside inside a controller seems, well, unusual for me.

I've always thought that messing around with threads in a web app isn't such a good idea, after all web apps are run on servers with their own ideas about threading (and a fixed thread pool for handling requests).

Does this have a bad smell about it? Am I worrying about nothing? How will spring handle the concurrent threads, by creating a new thread outside of the servers control or by using another thread from the server's pool?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like the best approach. Kicking off an async task to get a `Future`, then simply calling `Future.get` in the requesting thread means you've got **two** threads occupied - one doing the work for the async task and one waiting for that work to complete.

If something happens on the requesting thread in between the async task starting and the call to `get`, then I can understand this. Otherwise, it's better to simply make a synchronous call.

Comment: `If something happens on the requesting thread in between the async task starting and the call to get, then I can understand this.` - as I mentioned in me question, the requesting thread makes some ws calls.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood that. You could quite happily make those calls in parallel then. There is nothing really special about web application threads, and firing off new tasks for IO-bound work is quite sensible.